# Android Studio app crashes when variable is moved to base class rather than a final inside a function

Tags: java, android

Here is my code which works fine:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
final TextView numberTxtV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.numberTextV);
assert numberTxtV!=null;
numberTxtV.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,  int after) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int  count) {

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}
});
final TextView percentTextV=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.percentTextV);
final TextView resultTextV=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultTextV);
Button calcBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
assert calcBtn != null;
calcBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){public void onClick(View v){
if(!numberTxtV.getText().toString().equals("") && !percentTextV.getText().toString().equals("")){
float result = Float.parseFloat(numberTxtV.getText().toString())*Float.parseFloat(percentTextV.getText().toString())/100;
assert resultTextV != null;
resultTextV.setText(Float.toString(result));}
}});
```

When I grab resultTextV and put outside the function as a private var of the class the app crashes, why is that and how to go around it?

Comment: How does your app crash? Do you get an error or exception? Sharing this extra information will be useful in helping you in a better way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put `final TextView resultTextV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultTextV);` out of a function your app crashes because the view, where to look for the visual items, is not loaded.

You should use `findViewById(...)` only once the layout of the activity is defined, then after.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Usually this is done into the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` on into the `onResume()`.

Try it like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   TextView resultTextV;

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       resultTextV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultTextV);
       // ...
   }       
}
```

Comment: Right on the money, Thank a million.